# .h264 sample file

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, video-encoding

I'm currently using files [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425), but I get some errors while testing my program. I just want to see if it fails only with this one or with all other .h264 files. So, are there any other sources where I can download (standard) .h264 sample files for test ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: make your own with x264.  These are not standard sample files, but you can control which parts of H.264 they use, for example different profile/level/etc, make them I-frame-only, make them have only a particular macroblock type, etc.  Also you can make them tiny, e.g. one or a few frames long.

Option 2: perhaps the JM software comes with some sample files? http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/

Option 3: if you want to test a large number of files, download some random trailers etc in mp4 formar and demux them to get raw .h264 (for example with ffmpeg -vcodec copy)

Comment: `-ovc copy` is not a valid ffmpeg option. Looks like mencoder syntax to me.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -an -f h264 output.h264` works for me. Credits http://stackoverflow.com/a/29410927/2840115

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic movie for such testing:
[Big Buck Bunny](http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/)

Comment: It's too large (200+ MB) to test.

Comment: One weakness with Big Buck Bunny as testing data is the soundtrack. It consists mostly of "mood" music, so it can get out of sync by large fractions of a second -- or often several seconds -- before the error is noticeable (except for a few easily missed points where there are sound effects that align precisely with visual cues).