# Video Raw Samples using H264 Format

Tags: h.264

I need some video samples(without container) using H.264 but raw one to make some testing on.I have searched a lot but when I open certain file using VLC ,the file did not open.I have find a question on SO which has the same meaning ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399981/h264-sample-file))  but answer is not useful for me.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You are not asking a question, you are making a statement. Rule of thumb. A question ends in a question mark. You say what you need, then put restrictions on it, but don't say what the restriction are. And why is the answer not useful to you? It is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have been able to decipher this question. I am making an assumption that "is not useful for me." means "Doesn't play in VLC". By default, VLC wont play .264 files. Try adding `--demux h264` on the command line when launching VLC, or use mplayer to play the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,in the link I referred to I have three option and with each option I have a problem with each option,it is my h264 project so may be there is a missing knowledge,for **op1** I don't understand it,for **op2** I have not find the files ,for **op3** I still not able to demux it

Comment: What I am asking is just to have raw samples as in my project I get raw data encoded by h264 and I write it in a file (all byte streams) so I need something like this to test on it and compare mine with it,I hope that you got it.Thank u for the answer and sorry for my knowledge shortage

Comment: Please explain why you can't encode a sample using x264 for ffmpeg?