# How to extract('demux') from 'mp4' video to get the encoded data(or elementary stream) using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to `demux` from `mp4` video to get the video(`h264` format) elementary stream using `ffmpeg` command line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -an -f h264 output.h264`